# Merging these files

Tags: bash, loop-device

Having a sets of matched files in a folder, the name of each pair of files is like this with a basename, for instance

```
LP6005334-DNA_H01_vs_LP6005333-DNA_H01.passed.somatic.indels.vcf.parsed.txt
```

and

```
LP6005334-DNA_H01_vs_LP6005333-DNA_H01.passed.somatic.indels.vcf_fixed_vcf.txt.hg19_multianno.txt
```

How I can extract `columns 5th and 6th` from files with `passed.somatic.indels.vcf.parsed` in their file name and append these columns to the matched file (`passed.somatic.indels.vcf_fixed_vcf.txt.hg19_multianno`) returning an output ***.txt*** with the ***basename*** (`LP6005334-DNA_H01_vs_LP6005333-DNA_H01`)

For cutting the columns I done

[

```
fi1d18@cyan01 folder]$ for f in *.passed.somatic.indels.vcf.parsed.txt; do awk '{print $5,$6}' $f > $out
> done;
-bash: $out: ambiguous redirect
```

Hereafter I don't know how to find the matched find and append the cut columns to that

This is the link of a pair of these files

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4jx1rznswqz6dq/LP6008460-DNA_G03_vs_LP6008340-DNA_C05__pv.1.7__rg.grch37_g1k__al.bwa_mem__.passed.somatic.indels.vcf_fixed_vcf.txt.hg19_multianno.txt?dl=0

and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how your files are delimited, but you should be able to use something like

```
for f in *.vcf.parsed.txt; do 
  cut -f3,4 "$f" | paste "${f%.parsed.txt}_fixed_vcf.txt.hg19_multianno.txt" - > "${f%%.*}.txt"
done
```

The expansions `${f%.parsed.txt}` and `${f%%.*}` remove, respectively, the shortest and longest "dot suffixes" from the looped filename.

---

For the file pair

```
LP6008336-DNA_H02_vs_LP6008333-DNA_H02.snp.pass.txt                     
LP6008336-DNA_H02_vs_LP6008333-DNA_H02.snp.pass.txt.hg19_multianno.txt
```

which **don't** conform to the naming convention in your original question, you will need to change the pattern matches accordingly

ex.

```
for f in *.pass.txt; do
    cut -f60,61 "$f" | paste "$f.hg19_multianno.txt" - > "${f%%.*}.txt"; 
done
```

Comment: @Angel are the files named **exactly** as mentioned in your question? You seem to be inconsistent about whether they have a `.txt` extension or not.

Comment: @Angel I really strongly urge you to get used to using `.vcf` as the file extension and not `.txt`. As I told you over at [bioinformatics.se], the extension is usually irrelevant on Linux systems, but there are some tools that expect a `.vcf` or `.vcf.gz` extension.

Comment: @Angel I really strongly urge you to get used to using `.vcf` as the file extension and not `.txt`. As I told you over at [bioinformatics.se], the extension is usually irrelevant on Linux systems, but there are some tools that expect a `.vcf` or `.vcf.gz` extension.

Comment: @Angel I have updated the answer with the clarified filenames

Comment: @Angel if you change the naming convention of the files, then you will need to adjust the command to match - see updated answer

Comment: What is the **complete** error message? it looks like you are removing only `.pass.txt` but then appending `.snp.pass.vcf.txt.hg19_multianno.txt` - which will presumably lead to duplication of the `.snp` substring (`LP6005690-DNA_E01_vs_LP6005689-DNA_E01.snp.snp.pass.vcf.txt.hg19_multianno.txt`)